# Custom systemd service to run Gunicorn not working

Tags: django, server, gunicorn, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to deploy my Django website to a Ubuntu server. I am following this tutorial: linuxhint.com/create_django_app_ubuntu/. However, the Gunicorn service doesn't work.

I have my site at `/home/django/blog`.

My Python 3.6 virtualenv is activated at `/home/django/.venv/bin/activate` (`-rwxr-xr-x 1 django root 2207 Sep 21 14:07 activate`).

The script for starting the server is at `/home/django/bin/start-server.sh` (`-rwxr-xr-x 1 django root 69 Sep 21 15:50 start-server.sh`), with the following content:

```
cd /home/django
source .venv/bin/activate
cd blog
gunicorn blog.wsgi
```

Running this script manually works just fine.

The Gunicorn service is at `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`, with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=django
ExecStart=/home/django/bin/start-server.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Running `systemctl status gunicorn.service` gives this:

```
● gunicorn.service - Gunicorn
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-09-21 16:15:17 UTC; 6s ago
  Process: 1114 ExecStart=/home/django/bin/start-server.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 1114 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 21 16:15:17 example.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 21 16:15:17 example.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 21 16:15:17 example.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Sep 21 16:15:17 example.com systemd[1]: Stopped Gunicorn.
Sep 21 16:15:17 example.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 21 16:15:17 example.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 21 16:15:17 example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Gunicorn.
Sep 21 16:15:18 example.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 21 16:15:18 example.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 21 16:15:18 example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Gunicorn.
Sep 21 14:22:36 example.com systemd[7906]: gunicorn.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Sep 21 14:22:36 example.com systemd[7906]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/django/bin/start-server.sh: Permission denied
Sep 21 14:23:40 example.com systemd[7940]: gunicorn.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Sep 21 14:23:40 example.com systemd[7940]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/django/bin/start-server.sh: Permission denied
Sep 21 14:24:47 example.com systemd[7958]: gunicorn.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Sep 21 14:24:47 example.com systemd[7958]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/django/bin/start-server.sh: Permission denied
Permission denied
.
.
.
```

I ran `chown -R django:django /home/django`. Now, the output of `ls -lah /home/django` is:

```
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x 5 django django 4.0K Sep 21 14:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4.0K Sep 21 14:04 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 django django  220 Apr  4  2018 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 django django 3.7K Apr  4  2018 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 django django  807 Apr  4  2018 .profile
drwxr-xr-x 4 django django 4.0K Sep 21 14:07 .venv
drwxr-xr-x 2 django django 4.0K Sep 21 15:58 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 django django 4.0K Sep 21 14:08 blog
```

## Solution

Thanks to [Dmitry Belaventsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764182/dmitry-belaventsev), the solution to this is to change

```
ExecStart=/home/django/bin/start-server.sh
```

to

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/django/bin/start-server.sh
```

In the file `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`.

Comment: please update your question with the output of `ls -lah /home/django`

Comment: I think most likely you have permissions problem with some of the directories

Comment: Alright, I updated it

Comment: `chown -R /home/django django:django`

Comment: so you tell your systemd service to execute the script from behalf of the `django` user, but `/home/django` and `/home/django/bin` directories belong to `root:root`

Comment: Thank you for this. Been searching for a whole day and finally this solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your systemd service is setup to execute the script from behalf of `django` user. In the meantime:

`ls -lah /home/django`

```sh
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x 5 django django 4.0K Sep 21 14:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4.0K Sep 21 14:04 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 django django  220 Apr  4  2018 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 django django 3.7K Apr  4  2018 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 django django  807 Apr  4  2018 .profile
drwxr-xr-x 4 django root   4.0K Sep 21 14:07 .venv
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4.0K Sep 21 15:58 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4.0K Sep 21 14:08 blog
```

As you can see:

```sh
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4.0K Sep 21 14:04 ..
```

and

```sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4.0K Sep 21 15:58 bin
```

which means:

1. `/home` directory belongs to `root:root`
2. `/home/django/bin` belongs to `root:root`

To let `systemd` execute a bash script from behalf of `django` user:

1. That script should be executable
2. All parent directories should have execution rights
3. All those directories and the script should be available for `django` user

The quickest solution:

```sh
chown -R /home/django django:django
```

Also you could play with group and group rights as well.

Comment: I did that, but now the error is different (I edited my question).

Comment: Can you try `Restart=always` + `RestartSec=15`? And do you get any errors running that bash script manually? And did you try to run that script from behalf of `django` user manaully? You can login as `django` user with `su - django`. To get back to your previous user just use `exit`.

Comment: And I also suggest you to enable logging in your python application and/or in gunicorn. So you would be able to get some useful information about what's going wrong.

Comment: `Restart=always` + `RestartSec=15` gives me this `gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/django/bin/start-server.sh: Exec format error`.

Comment: Running it with the user `django` worked at first, but then I tried again and it just outputs `./start-server.sh: 2: ./start-server.sh: source: not found
./start-server.sh: 4: ./start-server.sh: gunicorn: not found
`

Comment: Can you execute `groups` command when you're logged in as `django` user in your linux shell? In the meantime, most likely you're in `sh` shell not in `bash`. Could you try `bash` right after the `su - django`?

Comment: Or just `sudo -u django bash` to login in bash

Comment: Ok, with bash, running `start-server.sh` works just fine. Running `groups` gives me `django`.

Comment: Could you setup some logging on app/gunicorn level? https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logging

Comment: So we can see what's going wrong on gunicorn/app side during systemd service startup

Comment: Yes, the app runs just fine. The problem is that the systemd service doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure how to get the logging. This is what running `gunicorn blog.wsgi` gives: `[2020-09-21 17:31:24 +0000] [2179] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-09-21 17:31:24 +0000] [2179] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (2179)
[2020-09-21 17:31:24 +0000] [2179] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-09-21 17:31:24 +0000] [2182] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2182
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221832/discussion-between-dmitry-belaventsev-and-marlon-cendron).